# Cleanly swap all occurences of two strings using sed

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a file that contains multiple occurrences of both StringA and StringB. I want to replace all occurrences of StringA with StringB, and (simultaneously) all occurrences of StringB with StringA.

Right now, I'm doing something like

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/StringB/StringC/g' | sed 's/StringA/StringB/g' | sed 's/StringC/StringA/g'
```

The problem with this approach is that it assumes StringC doesn't occur in the file. While this isn't an issue in practice, this solution still feels dirty -- that is, it feels like an opportunity to learn more unix magic. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `StringB` and `StringA` can't appear on the same input line, then you can tell sed to perform the replacement one way, and only try the other way if there were no occurrences of the first searched string.

```
<file.txt sed -e 's/StringA/StringB/g' -e t -e 's/StringB/StringA/g'
```

In the general case, I don't think there is an easy method in sed. By the way, note that the specification is ambiguous if `StringA` and `StringB` can overlap. Here's a Perl solution, which replaces the leftmost occurrence of either string, and repeats.

```
<file.txt perl -pe 'BEGIN {%r = ("StringA" => "StringB", "StringB" => "StringA")}
                    s/(StringA|StringB)/$r{$1}/ge'
```

If you want to stick with POSIX tools, awk is the way to go. Awk doesn't have a primitive for general parametrized replacements, so you need to roll your own.

```
<file.txt awk '{
    while (match($0, /StringA|StringB/)) {
        printf "%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART-1);
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART);
        printf "%s", /^StringA/ ? "StringB" : "StringA";
        $0 = substr($0, 1+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}'
```

Comment: When I run the first command, sed tells me `sed: can't read s/StringB/StringA/g: No such file or directory`. It seems `-e t PATTERN` isn't well understood.

Comment: @Gyscos There was a missing `-e` before the second `s` command. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 8):

> Right now, I'm doing something like
>   ...............
>   The problem with this approach is that it assumes StringC doesn't
>   occur in the file.

I think your approach is fine, you should just use something else instead of a string, something that cannot occur in a line (in the pattern space). The best candidate is the `\n`ewline.
Normally, no input line in the pattern space will contain that character so, to swap all occurrences of `THIS` and `THAT` in a file, you could run:

```
sed 's/THIS/\
/g
s/THAT/THIS/g
s/\n/THAT/g' infile
```

or, if your sed supports `\n` in the RHS too:

```
sed 's/THIS/\n/g;s/THAT/THIS/g;s/\n/THAT/g' infile
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I cried a little. Another way to do the RHS newlines is shell variables - whether the `sed` supports certain escapes or not becomes a lot less important if you prep a few macros beforehand. Like `set /THIS /THAT "$(printf \\n/)"; sed "s/$2/\\$4g;s/$3$2/g;s/\\n$3/g"` - kinda stupid here, admittedly, but it makes a lot more sense when some other times - especially for char classes and similar.

Comment: Well how about that, man. There's even an answer there about it. Was it there when I made the comment? I just saw the thing pop up on the recently edited list *(maybe)* and the top line of the top answer was a little off *(if you only care about non-embedded linux, I guess)*. I prefer Gilles's suggestion there - unless you're doing a long-running `sed`, the constant fork overhead with `e` is kinduva nightmare. On a different note - I've playing with `paste` for a whole day. I made an option parser - like `column` kind of. It just gens dashes for input strings and strings stuff together.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's perfectly valid to use a "nonce" string to swap two words. If you want a more general solution you can do something like:

```
sed 's/_/__/g; s/you/x_x/g; s/me/you/g; s/x_x/me/g; s/__/_/g' <<<"say you say me"
```

That yields

```
say me say you
```

Note that you need the two additional substitution here to avoid replacing `x_x` if you happen to have "x_x" strings. But even that still seems simpler than the `awk` solution for me.

Comment: That seems to be what the Asker said they were already doing.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that at first (see editing history) but my given solution is different since it works even when the replacement string (here "x_x") occurs in the original string, hence its more general.

Comment: Smart, but there's a catch. If StringA or StringB contains `_`, one needs to adjust the `_` itself (choose another character) or the troublesome string (perform `s/_/__/g` on it beforehand, seems better). Your solution, as it is, cannot be blindly applied to swap arbitrary strings.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't understand what you mean? I actually apply a `s/_/__/g` beforehand. Maybe just show a testcase which fails.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ah I think I understand now. You mean if the replacement strings itself contain a `_`, so say replacing `y_ou` with `me`. Yes it's true one have to be aware of that and put `y__ou` into the expression. A script which takes the replacement as input parameters also have to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from ages ago but in some cases you may use:

```
echo foobar | sed -e 's/bar/foo/' -e 's/foo/bar/'
```

This works because it replaces the first occurrence of `bar` first, and then the first occurrence of `foo`, leaving the second `foo` untouched. This assumes knowledge of the order in which they occur though, and only one occurrence.

This is a more agnostic version:

```
echo foobar | sed 's/foo/tmp/g' | sed -e 's/bar/foo/g' -e 's/tmp/bar/g'
```

```
$ echo barbarfoobar | sed 's/foo/tmp/g' | sed -e 's/bar/foo/g' -e 's/tmp/bar/g'
foofoobarfoo
```